# $d(x,Y)=0 \ \iff \ x\in\overline{Y}$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset\neq Y\subseteq X$. For $x\in X$ define $d(x,Y)=\inf\{d(x,y)|y\in Y\}$
>
> Show: $d(x,Y)=0$ iff $x\in\overline{Y}$

Proof:

We have,

$d(x,Y)=0\Leftrightarrow \inf\{d(x,y)|y\in Y\}=0\Leftrightarrow\forall\varepsilon >0 \exists y\in Y: d(x,y)<\varepsilon$

$\Leftrightarrow \forall\varepsilon>0:B_\varepsilon(x)\cap Y\neq\emptyset\Leftrightarrow x\in\overline{Y}$

Completing the proof.

Comment: Why do you have doubt than it could be not correct ?

Comment: @Surb Actually I do not... When I asked the question I had, but I was able to fix my concern. I attempted to proof both directions seperatly first, and made a mistake in the first, but noticed I can combine both directions like above, which made everything somehow simpler. I can not reconstruct my failure. Long story short: I decided to post my attempt anyways, since I kinda were already done.